# A Circular Div for a Target

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to make a circular button that can only be clicked in the circular part in order to execute a javascript function. It has to be made with HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, any JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY plugins or any combination of them. I have given a link to a picture outlining what I mean according to this explination: The black is the outline of the entire div (695px x 695px), if the blue is clicked nothing should happen but if the red is clicked the javascript function should be called.

Picture at: http://1drv.ms/1hIPvwz (new so couldnt post picture)

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is this a practical problem or is it an academic excersise (homework).  If it is practical, what is the actual requirement? What do you need help with?

Comment: Two options spring to mind. The use of image maps, or svg, both of which support circular clickable areas. Are either of these an option in your case? Of the two the use of images maps would seem to satisfy the requirement to stick with HTML better.

Comment: Put another `<div>` inside the outer one. Give it a `border-radius` of `100%`. Voilà.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use an SVG for this...

Any block element can have a border-radius: 100% applied to it, creating a rendered circle. I suggest putting a circular button within a block div. This would be best practice.

HTML

```
<div class="target">
    <button id="my-button">PRESS ME</button>   
</div>
```

CSS

```
button {
    background-color: red;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.target {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
    alert('pressed'); 
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9aRLp/1/

Answer (score 1):

SVG is the only solution I can think of. As an example:

your html:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle id="click" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

your jquery:

```
$('#click').click(function() {
   alert('clicked'); 
});
```

Comment: Downvoted because this answer goes way beyond what's needed and isn't a cross-browser solution.

Comment: That doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: on the cross-browser remark; more or less just as cross-browser as border radius: http://caniuse.com/svg http://caniuse.com/border-radius

Comment: On the over the top remark: I used less code.

Comment: Agreed- not a wrong answer, but given that the author didn't think to use border-radius, do you think it's wise to introduce drawing SVG's? I also hadn't Realized how ubiquitous drawing svgs was in terms of compatibility. My mistake.

Comment: I think we can both agree that best practice would not be drawing an SVG and using that as a button.

Answer (score 0):

Sitting in the exact middle of the blue box.

Have a fiddle! - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/cG2Np/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
<a class="circle" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    height: 550px;
    width: 550px;
    background: #000080;
    position: relative;
}
.circle {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #F00;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -250px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.circle').click(function() {
    alert('pressed'); 
});
```